# Inheriting constructors from superclass?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I have a class called Robot.java:

```
class Robot {
String name;
int numLegs;
float powerLevel;

Robot(String productName) {
    name = productName;
    numLegs = 2;
    powerLevel = 2.0f;
}

void talk(String phrase) {
    if (powerLevel >= 1.0f) {
        System.out.println(name + " says " + phrase);
        powerLevel -= 1.0f;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(name + " is too weak to talk.");
    }
}

void charge(float amount) {
    System.out.println(name + " charges.");
    powerLevel += amount;
}
}
```

and a subclass called TranslationRobot.java:

```
public class TranslationRobot extends Robot {
    // class has everything that Robot has implicitly
    String substitute; // and more features

    TranslationRobot(String substitute) {
        this.substitute = substitute;
    }

    void translate(String phrase) {
        this.talk(phrase.replaceAll("a", substitute));
    }

    @Override
    void charge(float amount) { //overriding
        System.out.println(name + " charges double.");
        powerLevel = powerLevel + 2 * amount;
    }
}
```

When I compile TranslationRobot.java, I get the following error:

```
TranslationRobot.java:5: error: constructor Robot in class Robot cannot be applied to given types;
TranslationRobot(String substitute) {
                                    ^
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I understand this is referring to something about inheriting from the superclass but I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a subclass always needs to call the constructor of its parent class when it gets constructed. If the parent class has a no-argument constructor, this happens automatically. But your `Robot` class only has a constructor which takes a `String`, so you need to explicitly call it. This can be done with the `super` keyword.

```
TranslationRobot(String substitute) {
    super("YourProductName");
    this.substitute = substitute;
}
```

Or, if you want to give each `TranslationRobot` a unique product name, you could take an extra argument in the constructor and use that:

```
TranslationRobot(String substitute, String productName) {
    super(productName);
    this.substitute = substitute;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, does it matter what I put inside the super method as long as it's a string? could I write Robot.name?

Comment: @user6731064 You can put whatever you want (as long as it's a String), but `this.name` - which I think is what you mean - won't do what you want. Remember that `name` doesn't have a value yet. That's what that constructor is for. My guess is that what you want is to have `TranslationRobot` take two `String`s in it's contructor, and use one of them as the argument to `super`.